# Checkbox not checking back after deleting text and typing

Tags: jquery, checkbox, textbox, keyboard-events

I'm trying to make some kind of auto checking/unchecking function for grid:

`Check [x] | Data1 | Data2 | Order: [____]`

Below is code which I've came up with, problem: when I type in textbox -> checkbox is checking - OK, then I delete text -> unchecking - OK, then when I type anything again checkbox is not checking as it should. I'm thinking if the `row` variable might be causing that but I'm not sure about it. Please help.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 0;
    $(".grid > tbody > tr").each(function () {
        if (counter > 0) {
            var row = $(this);
            $(this).find("input[type=text]").keyup(function () {
                var tinput = $(this).val();
                var chkbox = row.find("input[type=checkbox]");
                if (tinput.length == 0) {
                    chkbox.attr("checked", false);
                } else {
                    chkbox.attr("checked", true);
                }
            });
        } else counter = counter + 1;
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JSDQ6/

Comment: Show us the fiddle...

Comment: @Alvaro - updated with link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to loop through them and attach an event handler. Just target all of them from the beginning, since they are similar ---> [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jafrisella/JSDQ6/1/)

```
$('table tr:gt(0) input[type="text"]').keyup(function(){
      var val = $.trim($(this).val());
      var chkBox = $(this).parent().parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]');
   if(val.length > 0){
       chkBox.prop('checked', true);
   }else{
       chkBox.prop('checked',false);
   }
});
```

Comment: Almost perfect, but when I type into the textbox all checkboxes are being checked instead of that within current row where I type.

Comment: @AdrianK. What does your new code look like. I have a fiddle at the top of my answer showing it working?

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/dare/k9jKu/ but this table is nested in another, so I think that this might be a reason why each checkbox is being checked in.

Comment: @AdrianK. change `$('table tr:gt(0) input[type="text"]')` to `$('.grid tr:gt(0) input[type="text"]')`  my answer is targeting all tables. But you want to change the beginning to just target the single table.  It looks like you have changed already

Comment: @AdrianK. I see [NEW FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jafrisella/k9jKu/1/). It is because of `.parents('tr')`, it grabs all parents.  changed to `.parent().parent()` . this should keep it out of upper table

Comment: I see [APPRECIATION](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e3/NCI_Visuals_Food_Beer.jpg) for your work! This solved my problem completely. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

Do not use .attr() for checking a checkbox because 'checked="checked"' is not an attribute but it is a property. Very common misconception/issue. I used to do the same thing and it drove me up a wall one day lol.

Instead use this:

```
chkbox.prop("checked", false); //unchecks a checkbox
chkbox.prop("checked", true);  //checks a checkbox
```

Just for future reference, apply the same logic for selects as well:

```
$('select').find('option.choice1').prop('selected', true);
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I will for sure start using `prop` instead of `attr`